# how to change a positive number to negative and vice versa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm thinking there must be a function to do both.
I think fabs will do negative to positive.

But not sure about the other way around ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`num *= -1` will change the sign from positive to negative and vice versa.

Comment: Changing the sign is much more idiomatically done using the `-` operator. This is fundamentally an additive operation rather than a multiplicative one.

Answer (score 12):

I would rather write like this:

```
num = -num;
```

This won't need a multiplication, just changing the sign.

Comment: You can even avoid subtraction using `num=(-1^num)++;` . Of course, only for integers.

Comment: Optimizing compilers would not use multiplication or even an assignment in either case: even if you write `num = -1 * num`, modern compilers would optimize out the multiplication, and use the `NEG $num` instruction to negate the number in place.

Comment: changing the sign is better than using multiplication as will actually multiply the number and of course the effect will change the sign, yet on the multiplied number.